# How to change Qt Creator default file names

Tags: qt-creator

Is it possible to change the default pattern for file names when adding a new class to a project in Qt Creator?

E.g. if I add a class named "**FooBar**", the dialog uses "**foobar.h**" and "**foobar.cpp**" as defaults, but I would like to have "**FooBar.h**" and "**FooBar.cpp**".

Of course I can change the names manually, but when adding many classes it can be a bit annoying.

**I am using Qt Creator 3.3.2**